# React is rendering my components as their name instead of what's in them

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a "FormBuilder" component that iterates through a list of objects and iterates an input based on the listed type.

I have an 'enum' (I know it's not really an enum, because it's Javascript), that associates a constant term with a certain component name, like this:

```
const InputTypes = Object.freeze({
    TEXT: 'TextInput',
    PASSWORD: 'PasswordInput',
    SUBMIT: 'SubmitInput',
    RESET: 'ResetInput',
    RADIO: 'RadioInput',
    CHECKBOX: 'CheckboxInput',
    BUTTON: 'ButtonInput',
    DATE: 'DateInput',
    EMAIL: 'EmailInput',
    NUMBER: 'NumberInput',
    TIMEINTERVAL: 'TimeIntervalInput'
});
```

Each of the strings is the name of a component. I won't list them all, but here's a sample, 'TextInput':

```
function TextInput(props) {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <label>
                {props.name}:
                <input
                    type='text'
                    name={props.name.toLowerCase()}
                    value={props.value}
                    onChange = {props.handlers.handleChange}
                    {...props.attributes}
                />
            </label>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}

export default TextInput;
```

Now I have a 'FormBuilder' component that iterates through a bunch of objects containing a `type` property:

```
render() {
    return <form id={this.props.id}>
        {

            this.props.inputFields.map(input=>{
                const propsWithKeyAndHandlers = Object.assign({
                    key:"" + this.props.task._id + input.props.name,
                    handlers:this.props.handlers,
                    value: this.props.task[input.props.name]}
                    ,input.props);
                return input.content?
                    React.createElement(input.type, propsWithKeyAndHandlers, input.content):
                    React.createElement(input.type, propsWithKeyAndHandlers);
            })
        }
    </form>
```

An example of the kind of data that gets passed to this component would be:

```
        inputFields: [
            {props: {name:'name', },type:InputTypes.TEXT},
            {props: {name: 'description'}, type:InputTypes.TEXT},
            {props: {name:'deadline'},type:InputTypes.DATE},
            {props:{name:'startDate'},type:InputTypes.DATE},
            {props: {name:'external'},type:InputTypes.CHECKBOX},
            {props: {name:'estTime'},type:InputTypes.NUMBER}
        ],
```

So here's a sample of what I see in the React developer console when I run this:

[image: React console screenshot]

As you can see it's rendering the correct component, but it's just listing the component name, not what's in the component.

How do I get React to render what's in the component as I'd expect it to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `InputTypes` object needs to reference the actual components, not a string. For example

```
import TextInput from "./TextInput.jsx";
...

const InputTypes = Object.freeze({
    TEXT: TextInput,
    ...
});
```

Your 'enum' links to strings that just happen to have the same name as your components, it doesn't link to the actual components. You can't use strings to refer to the component name by default. There's no magical, inherent link between a string and a component with that same name.

Comment: Okay, I get it. I thought it should be a string because that's how you do it when it's not a variable. But this works, thanks.